# Proxy Setting in Android SDK

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I set up proxy in Android AVD Emulator (in order to execute web based android applications)?
How do I set up proxy in SDK Manager.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Kobi

Answer (score 3):

We have to add additional command line options in the SDK.
it can be done in Run>Debug Configurations/Run Configurations
Tab Target> Additional Emulator Command Line Options.

The additional options are: `-http-proxy http://<user name>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>`

more details can be found at: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 2):

For that in emulator go in **settings->Wireless** and **networks->mobile networks->access points->Telkila** .Here you can set proxy and port for your system. Then try to browse Google or other site in your emulator browser.

Answer (score 1):

To set proxy for SDK manager, just open up the SDK manager either from Eclipse or the exe itself, click on "Tools, then click on "Options" and you will see the Proxy input info.